# I need to know about netsuite integration

Tags: netsuite

Hai,

i need to details about netsuite integration, i am using PHPtoolkit.php file for getting datas from client netsuite server.

i need to fetch category,products details from netsuite server.

I would be very happy if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The netsuite PHPToolkit, from my experience, is very hard to work with. I've had to do some integration with netsuite, mostly with custom records created in netsuite, and have wrapped the base layer I'm using for netsuite communication into a [Kohana 2 module](https://github.com/iloveitaly/netsuite-kohana). There have also been a couple of fixes to the PHPToolkit.php that I have made that might be helpful (check the commit logs).

Although the module is written with Kohana 2 in mind, there really is only a couple things here and there that reference the Kohana library (mostly the config & log functionality). You should be able to find some information within the comments + code examples to help you out (although it isn't very well documented or explained right now).

As Daniel mentioned the netsuite user group is a great place for assistance. Here are some links that have helped me in learning and debugging netsuite:

- [Netsuite Schema Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/indexv2011_1_0.html)
- [SuiteTalk Archives](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-archives.shtml) – you can grab the wsdl from here
- [SuiteTalk Records Guide](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteFlex/WebServices/SuiteTalkWebServicesRecordsGuide.html)
- [Me.Thoughts.ToString](http://kikosantos.net/tech/) - blog with some netsuite source
- [NetSuite FAQ](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/AdditionalResources/FAQ_WebServicesFAQ.html)

Although this doesn't answer your question about products + categories, hopefully this will point you in the right direction & give you some resources to help you along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a number of useful scripts with the PHP toolkit.   They're all command-line tools, which is a little odd, but it was the only interpreted language supported by NetSuite.  If you're comfortable with PHP it can be done.  Also the "beta" designation seems to be gone now.

One in particular is documented here:  http://dgts.dreamgearweb.com/tech-corner/netsuite

It does something that is otherwise impossible - it imports units of measure.

I also have one that imports inventory adjustments but this is "sort of" possible now with the latest version of netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience pulling and pushing data to and from the NetSuite system. I would suggest using C# or Java because this is easier and more documented from NetSuite. The PHPtoolkit is still in beta mode.

Answer (score 0):

This blog has a few posts about using the php Toolkit with Netsuite:
[Ozone and Programming](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/category/beginning-with-the-phptoolkit/)

It has several code examples which you can build off of.  I would also recommend posting on the Netsuite User Group Forums.  It is a handy resource: [User Group](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/)

If you search the forums, you can usually find some sample code involving the records you are dealing with. (you have to register, but it is free)

Answer (score 0):

What matters is understanding Netsuite schema and record relationships. PHPToolkit ships with only a couple of code examples, which makes it very difficult for novice to come up to speed.

Web Traffic Exchange has some good resources with code examples on Netsuite.

http://www.webtrafficexchange.com/tags/netsuite

Comment: Are you affiliated with the site you are linking to?